# Does any OpenGL versions require support for Frame Buffer Objects?

Tags: opengl, fbo

Is support for Frame Buffer Objects (FBO) required by any versions of the OpenGL standard? Or is it a purely optional extension?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

FBOs have been in core since [3.0](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Framebuffer_Object).